How can I set org-download-image-dir depending on the hostname?
For some reason, setting the org-image-download-dir after init doesn't work.
It works if I do this:
(when (string-equal (system-name) "quasar")
 (use-package org-download
    :after org
    :defer nil
    :custom
    (org-download-method 'directory)
    (org-download-image-dir "~/mnt/quasar-org-download")
    (org-download-heading-lvl nil)
    :config
    (require 'org-download))
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'org-download-enable)
   )

, but I'd rather have some simpler logic;)

How do you try to change it after init? How do you know it does not work?

Define "some simpler logic". Opinion-based.
